# Flameshot doesn't Work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I'm usint Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8, and installed Flameshot from Ubuntu Software. Installation goes fine, no error received, but when I click on the icon, or call `flameshot` from terminal nothing happens.

Does anyone had this same issue and found a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leonardo, try

```
flameshot gui
```

And also from [docs](https://flameshot.org/key-bindings/), if want to define shortcut:

Open Settings → Devices → Keyboard → Shortcuts.

Search for 'print', and unbind the screen capture function by selecting it, and clicking backspace.

Scroll down and click on the '+'.

On 'Name', name it 'Flameshot' or 'PrintScreen'.

Define the command as 'flameshot gui'.

Select 'Define shortcut...'and click your keyboard Prt Sc key.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 21.04. I've installed snapcraft.io version from Software Center.
The only solution I've found for now - install ubuntu-hirsute-universe version from Software Center or via terminal. It works good.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Then I realized the tray icon was not enabled - don't know why and I don't recall this happening on another machine I have that is also on Ubuntu 20.04.

I fixed it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
flameshot config
```

This results in flameshot's configuration dialogue being shown. I then navigated to the **General** tab and checked the **Show tray icon** checkbox.

[flameshot config dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJBg5.png)